# What does =/xyz like expressions for Batch File

Tags: batch-file

```
set batVar_Parameters=/Developer /Test=0

if not '%batVar_Iteration%' equ '-1' (
    set batVar_Parameters=%batVar_Parameters%  /Iteration=%batVar_Iteration%
)

if not '%1' equ '' (
    set batVar_Parameters=%batVar_Parameters%  /DeveloperBuildIniFile=%1
)
```

I'm translating Batch File to C# and I face with an expression "=/xyz" depicted above.  What does it mean exactly?

Comment: It would be nice if you showed that part of the code where the expression `=/xyz` is in. Or do you simply mean any of the SET commands? Like `set batVar_Parameters=/Developer /Test=0`, which settint the variable `batVar_Parameters` to the content `/Developer /Test=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"set abc=/xyz" means nothing special, it's just "=" followed by the contents of the variable, which happened to start with "/". It's probably meant as a parameter to a program, like in "dir /a".

Try this:

```
set batVar_Parameters=/Developer /Test=0

echo testing%batVar_Parameters%testing
```

It'll give you:

```
testing/Developer /Test=0testing
```